# The message filter indicated that the application is busy

Tags: c#, ms-word

When I try to read content of word doc by `oWordDoc.Content`,
It throws exception:

> The message filter indicated that the application is busy. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER))

I tried `OApplication.Visible = false`,
It also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is another instance of msword already working on background, maybe invisible and displaying some message box nobody will click on. Try to kill that instance by task manager, then try to ensure you are closing msword when you use it in automation.